# Why does my background colour end?

Tags: html, css, background-color

I am creating a footer for a webpage and for some reason, I can't get the background colour to fill the whole div once I start populating it.

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SEB3S/)

```
.widefooter {
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    width:100%;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

After I add the "links" under the `<hr>` the background colour of the footer just ends, even though the links are nested in the footer div, not after it.

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Please post the code.. from the looks of screenshot, if you use `overflow: auto` to `.widefooter` should work. Looks like a problem of floating elements which need to be cleared.

Comment: @Mr_Green I've posted a jsfiddle with all the code

Comment: Try `overflow: hidden`. auto is giving scroll...

Comment: Here's another solution: http://jsfiddle.net/SEB3S/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` to `.widefootercontent`.

Floated elements do not contribute to the parent container's height unless specifically done so with this `overflow` property.

Comment: Thank you Niet! I didn't know that float ignores the parents height.

Comment: @SaturnsEye How else would elements below them float alongside? ;)

Comment: I fixed it by adding `position: absolute` to `widefooter`. http://jsfiddle.net/SEB3S/4/

Comment: @Claudio thank you, but Niet already fixed the problem for me. Plus you should post that as a separate answer, not as a comment on someone elses answer.

Comment: @SaturnsEye I guess that'd be better.

Comment: @SaturnsEye it's just some kind of addition to the answer, he might not want to add an answer because doing so **always** requires explanation and much more info and someone may feel a little lazy to add it.

Comment: @KingKing Actually, I just happened to fix it. I have no logical explanation for it. But I could comment it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem of floating elements. which need to be cleared by a third element specially created for clearing floats.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="clearFloat"></div>  <!-- for clearing above float elements -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clearFloat {
    clear: both;
}
```

I always prefer adding a last child element to clear the floats instead of using `overflow :hidden` property because if the child element needs to be shown outside of the parent element using position: absolute then overflow: hidden will hide the child. which is really frustrating in bigger projects.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SEB3S/6/)**